# show alert No data found between dates while calling ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

i am using java Servlet for server side programming, i am returning a Json object which i am getting with ajax call. i just want to show a alert box , if there is no data found between dates entered by user then a alert text should come on my jsp page.

here is my JSP and servlet code iam using some method to do that but not getting success please any one guide me.

**jsp (i am using JSP as a view)**

```
<form id="formid" action="BarServlet" method="get">
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Start Date:</h4>
        <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276"
            placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
        <h4>End Date:</h4>
        <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276"
            placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />


        <h4>Outlets:</h4>
        <select id="all" name="outlet">
            <option>ALL</option>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj.outlet}">
                <option>${item}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <h5 class="NoDataFound"><%=(request.getAttribute("NoDataFound") == null) ? "" : request.getAttribute("NoDataFound")%></h5>
        <div>
            <br>
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**This is my servlet**

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

```
        try {
            con = DBConnection.createConnection();
            statement = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
                   request.setAttribute("NoDataFound", "NO Data Found"); 
                      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp.jsp");
                      dispatcher.forward( request, response);


            }
            while (resultSet.next()) {


> if data is found them this will execute

                list.add(map);
                str = gson.toJson(list);

            }
//System.out.println(list);
            response.setContentType("application/json");

            response.getWriter().write(str);



}
```

**And here is my JavaScript file**

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#formid").submit(
                function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault(); // to stop form being submitted because it reloads the page.
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "BarServlet",
                        method : "GET",
                        data : {
                            fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),
                            todate : $("#enddate").val(),
                            outlet : $("#all").val()
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                            $("#formid").hide(); // this will hide the form.
                            var paymentmode = [];
                            var amount = [];
                             console.log(data)
                            for ( var i in data) {
                                paymentmode.push(data[i].CashamountX);
                                amount.push(data[i].CashamountY);

                                paymentmode.push(data[i].SwiggyAmtX);
                                amount.push(data[i].SwiggyAmtY);

                                paymentmode.push(data[i].KBAmtX);
                                amount.push(data[i].KBAmtY);

                                paymentmode.push(data[i].BigBasketAmtX);
                                amount.push(data[i].BigBasketAmtY);

                                paymentmode.push(data[i].ZomatoAmtX);
                                amount.push(data[i].ZomatoAmtY);

                                paymentmode.push(data[i].CreditCardAmtX);
                                amount.push(data[i].CreditCardAmtY);

                                paymentmode.push(data[i].CouponAmtX);
                                amount.push(data[i].CouponAmtY);

                                paymentmode.push(data[i].PayTMAmtX);
                                amount.push(data[i].PayTMAmtY);

                                paymentmode.push(data[i].CreditAmtX);
                                amount.push(data[i].CreditAmtX);
                            }
                             Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
                            var chartdata = {
                                labels : paymentmode,
                                datasets : [ {

                                    backgroundColor : [ "#87CEFA",
                                                        "#B0C4DE",
                                                        "#AFEEEE",
                                                        "#00BFFF",
                                                        "#87CEFA",
                                                        "#1E90FF",
                                                        "#708090",
                                                        "#778899",
                                                        "#696969",
                                                        "#808080" ],
                                                        borderColor : 'black',
                                    hoverBackgroundColor : '    #9370DB',
                                    hoverBorderColor : 'red',
                                    data : amount
                                } ],


                            };

                            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

                            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                                type : 'bar',
                                data : chartdata
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
    });
```

Comment: please guyz any one help me out

Comment: what are you getting is data? in success callback ?

Comment: if user provide dates where data is present then its shows the bar graph,but if user provide dates where there is no data then also it success but chart is blank.i just wanted to show the alert on second scenario and my form should not hide

Comment: i have tried that but that's not working.in if i provide all success code and in else i provided alert.but nothing happned